# Derivative of a function involving factorials

Tags: derivatives

If $\dfrac{d}{dx}$  $\dfrac{(2x+1)!}{(2^x\cdot x!)^2}$ $\backsim$ $f(x)$ can $f(x)$  be written only in terms of elementary functions and factorials. And what could $f(x)$ be?

Comment: Do you mean $2^x\cdot x!$ or $(2^x\cdot x)!$?

Comment: The first one,didn't know how to put the multiplication sign,sry:).

Comment: Do you judge the digamma function $\Psi$ as elementary?

Comment: the final answer should only have elementary functions like exponents, log basic arthimatic .and the "!" Function

Comment: You want $\frac d{dx}\frac{(2x+1)!}{(2^xx!)^2}\sim f(x)$, instead of $\frac d{dx}\frac{(2x+1)!}{(2^xx!)^2}=f(x)$?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the factorial has no derivative as it is a discrete function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

By applying [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):

> $$n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac n e\right)^n,$$

$$\require{cancel }\frac{(2x+1)!}{(2^x\cdot x!)^2}=\frac{(2x+1)(2x)!}{(2^x\cdot x!)^2}\sim\frac{(2x+1)\sqrt{2\pi (2x)}\bcancel{\left(\frac {2x} e\right)^{2x}}}{\bcancel{2^{2x}}\cdot(2\pi x)\bcancel{\left(\frac x e\right)^{2x}}}=\frac{2x+1}{(\pi x)^{\frac 12}}.$$

Therefore $f$ can be obtained by

$$\frac d {dx}\left( \frac{2x+1}{(\pi x)^{\frac 12}}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want

$$x!:=\Gamma(x+1)$$

then the only problem is differentiating the factorials, as everything else can be done with a combination of products rules, quotient rules, and chain rules (no pun intended). 
 We have

$$\frac d{dx}x!=x!\psi(x+1)$$

where $\psi(x+1)$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).  Assuming $x\in\mathbb N$, we have the [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)

$$\psi(x+1)=-\gamma+H_x=-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^x\frac1k$$

> $$\frac d{dx}=x!\left[-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^x\frac1k\right],~x\in\mathbb N$$

Where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)

$$\gamma:=\int_1^\infty\frac1{\lfloor x\rfloor}-\frac1x~\mathrm dx$$